# dynamically close row div in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm just trying out bootstrap and it seems great, but I'm running into a problem that seems far too difficult to solve than seems right.

I have a masonry-like format that shows three columns, then goes onto a new row an indefinite number of times.

```
x x x
x x x
x x x
```

Which (as far as I understand) has to be coded like this in bootstrap:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

But does that mean in the views of my code (such as rails), I need to do some sort of loop that monitors every 3 times and then closes the row and starts a new one? I'd assume this is something bootstrap would be able to handle on its own.

```
for($i=0;i<3;i++) {
   do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/9RrX7/

Create a new container for your dynamic content and simply dump everything into the same row. Then use CSS:nth child selector to select the 4th, 7th, ... dynamic content item and tweak the CSS so the floating works correctly.

I included some extra content to check the floating and resizing is working correctly.

CSS

```
.dynamic .row .span4:nth-child(3n+4) {  
clear:both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="span4">X</div>
<div class="span4">X</div>
<div class="span4">X</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span4">X</div>
<div class="span4">X</div>
<div class="span4">X</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="span4">X</div>
<div class="span4">X</div>
<div class="span4">X</div>
</div>
</div>

</div><!-- end container -->

<div class="container-fluid dynamic">
<div class="row">

<div class="span4"></div>
<div class="span4"></div>
<div class="span4"></div>
<!-- repeat as req'd -->
</div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

========================================================

Dynamic HTML could be added by using javascript or php. For example say you are using php, content is coming from a database, and your bootstrap page is .php .

The general layout of the bootstrap page could be something like this:

```
<?php connect to database and read in data ?>

<head> ...</head>
<body>
.......
......

<div class="container-fluid dynamic">
<div class="row">

<?php loop through data ?>
<div class="span4"> <?php echo $item data ?> </div>
<?php end loop ?>

</div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't understand, this is entirely static. I was wondering how to dynamically close the rows.

Comment: Hi, to clarify, is your problem how to accomodate an unknown number of span4 divs into your page, or is it how to get html code that's generated dynamically into your bootstap layout?

Comment: I had assumed that they are the same thing. If you were to accommodate an unknown number of span4 divs onto a page, don't you have to dynamically generate the ending row tag?